# Repairing small spot on epoxy table damaged by adhesive

Tags: technique-selection, epoxy-resin, maintenance

After setting up a new epoxy table as a computer desk, I placed a small keyboard stand with rubber feet on it. Unfortunately, it seems like the rubber feet had some sort of adhesive coating on them, which I only discovered after trying to move the stand after two days. I used a combination of a small amount of Goo Gone and water to remove the adhesive, which worked, but the end result is a hazy spot on the epoxy.Although this spot will not be visible under normal circumstances, it still bothers me given that the table was just purchased.

The only way I see to completely remove the spot would be to wet sand using a 2000 to 3000 grit sanding block, and then following up with a cutting compound and polish. The rest of the table is in perfect condition, so I'm wondering if this will work without having to do the entire surface.

See below image of damage:

[image]

Comment: I understand your wish of restoring the "perfect" finish of this brand new table, but I suggest you wait at least a month or two to assess how vulnerable to scratches this table is. Most epoxies are brittle and accumulate micro-scratches that eventually (over years) give them a matte finish. Big forces can cause deeper and very visible scratches. Spills of strongly colored liquids like tomato sauce, mustard or artificially colored sodas can leave permanent stains. It would be devastating to have to touch up the surface again after a short time.

Comment: Rubber feet aren't natural rubber, and contain plasticisers of some sort.  These can leach out in contact with some other materials (I've had trouble against metallic spray paint, for example).  Whatever you do in the short term, you might want a mat of some sort under your keyboard

Comment: Could you upload more photos? It's really hard to see what's happening in the current one. Maybe from slightly different angles, and one close-up (or a video, preferably).